# The type or namespace name `OpenCVForUnity' could not be found

Tags: unity

I am working on face traching in unity3D

I have downloaded and imported the sample project on "FaceTracker Sample using OpenCV for Unity".

But when I tried to runned the project,its showing me the error.Below is the screen shot of the error

[image]

What will be the issue?can anybody help out please?

I am using unity(5.0.0f4(64 bit))

Answer (score 0):

If in case the script is in plugin folder , try shifting it to some other location. Most of the plugins start giving such errors while porting form unity 4 to 5. Also try the "using" statement at the top of the class. For example for facebook i had to do "using Facebook.Unity"